# RubyMine - NoMethodError: Undefined method 'get' for nil:nilClass - Webdriver UserAgent

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, user-agent, rubymine

I am new to RubyMine and trying to debug an project that I did not write myself.

The error when I ran the Project.feature and it stopped at the first line 'Given I go to this Website'.

```
"NoMethodError: Undefined method 'get' for nil:nilClass" in filepath/Common_steps_json.rb:14 in '/^I go to this website$'
```

Going to the link provided, it directed me to my Common_steps_json.rb file where the code written was

```
Given /^I go to this website$/ do
@driver.get 'https://www.somewebsite.com/field1/field2/'
sleep 3
end
```

I believe this is the correct format to navigate to a URL using Selenium-Webdriver. So this prompted me to check the environment file env.rb to see how the driver was called. There I found this.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "webdriver-user-agent"
.
.
. 
Before('@driver_iphone_portrait') do
@driver = UserAgent.driver(:browser => :firefox, :agent => :iphone, :orientation =>      :portrait)
@base_url = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/'
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 2
@verification_errors = []
end
```

I checked this [link](http://watirmelon.com/2012/03/27/introducing-webdriver-user-agent-gem-a-quick-way-to-run-ruby-webdriver-tests-emulating-mobile-devices/) to make sure that the selenium webdriver user agent was called correctly but I am not so sure that it is. I used Interactive Ruby to see if I could call the driver using the UserAgent.Driver format but it ran into a error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant UserAgent
```

If anyone has any advice on how to properly format UserAgent for RubyMine, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is trying to run some tests using Firefox with a profile that uses a user agent property to emulate the iPhone.

<strike>Unfortunately, your code is using a [depreciated gem](http://watirmelon.com/2013/03/15/webdriver-user-agent-gem-has-been-deprecated/) written by Alister Scott. You will be unable to continue to use this gem, and should look for a work around.</strike>

**UPDATE** Alister Scott [just announced that the maintenance of the gem has been taken over by Jeff "Cheezy" Morgan](http://watirmelon.com/2013/06/04/webdriver-user-agent-gem-has-a-new-owner/) and is available on the [Github repo](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent).

---

In fact, it looks like this was a pretty simple and standard gem wrapper that you can employ without all the sugary wrapper goodness. Actually, you can easily configure this setting in your [WebDriver Profile setup](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Changing_the_user_agent)

Try something like this to replace the UserAgent string (and take out the `require 'webdriver-user-agent'` line too):

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["general.useragent.override"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3"
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

That should create the `@driver` object and allow you to use the `get` method to open the website with the Firefox browser. The browser should be sending in the headers of the requests the user agent you specified in the code, and your web pages should be rendering as they would if an iPhone was browsing.

Comment: Thanks bgoad! I didn't know the gem used in the code was depreciated. The workaround does a brilliant job setting up the @driver to display the webpage as an Iphone would.